# Openiddict. Unable to reach Accept(Deny) authorization endpoint for Authorization Code flow

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, openiddict

I use the Openiddict library for OAuth2 authentification on the server side. We use Asp.Net Core - server side, Angular 2  - client side. After processed Authorize request, the server redirects to the following URL with user confirmation form. See example code below:

```
 [Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    [Route(RouteConst.OAuth.AUTHORIZE)]
    [EnableCors(CommonConst.ALLOW_ALL)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Authorize()
    {
        var request = this.HttpContext.GetOpenIdConnectRequest();
        // Retrieve the application details from the database.
        var application = await this._applicationManager.FindByClientIdAsync(request.ClientId, this.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
        if (application == null)
        {
            return this.BadRequest(new ErrorUI
            {
                Error = OpenIdConnectConstants.Errors.InvalidClient,
                ErrorDescription = "Details concerning the calling client application cannot be found in the database"
            });
        }

        return this.Redirect($"/app/profile?oauth={request.Scope}&application={application.DisplayName}&requestId={request.RequestId}");
    }
```

After redirect user can see the confirmation form then click Accept(Deny) button.  In [Openiddict Code samples](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples/blob/master/samples/CodeFlow/AuthorizationServer/Controllers/AuthorizationController.cs) is used MvcBinders and Razor views, but when I tried to create similar POST request to the server from Angular view - OpenIdConnectRequest is null.

Why is OpenIdConnectRequest null after redirect to the local URL? Can I reach the Accept Authorize endpoint within CORS POST request without using MVC?

Startup setup:

```
 services.AddOpenIddict(options =>
        {
            options.AddEntityFrameworkCoreStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            options.EnableAuthorizationEndpoint(RouteConst.OAuth.AUTHORIZE)
                .EnableLogoutEndpoint(RouteConst.OAuth.LOGOUT)
                .EnableTokenEndpoint(RouteConst.OAuth.TOKEN)
                .EnableUserinfoEndpoint(RouteConst.USERINFO);

            options.AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow();

            options.EnableRequestCaching();
        });
```

Accept endpoint:

```
 [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route(RouteConst.OAuth.AUTHORIZE)]
    [FormValueRequired("submit.Accept")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Accept()
    {
        var request = this.HttpContext.GetOpenIdConnectRequest();
        // Retrieve the profile of the logged in user.
        var user = await this._userManager.GetUserAsync(this.User);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return this.BadRequest(new ErrorUI
            {
                Error = OpenIdConnectConstants.Errors.ServerError,
                ErrorDescription = "An internal error has occurred"
            });
        }

        // Create a new authentication ticket.
        var ticket = await this.CreateTicketAsync(request, user);

        // Returning a SignInResult will ask OpenIddict to issue the appropriate access/identity tokens.
        return this.SignIn(ticket.Principal, ticket.Properties, ticket.AuthenticationScheme);
    }
```

Comment: It's important to note that the authorization endpoint is NOT supposed to be used by API clients. The fact you have to use CORS for the authorization endpoint makes me think you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Hi @Pinpoint, thank you for the answer. I used the web API authorization endpoints, so Openiddict middleware recognizes as independent calls. I created duplication Razor views with MVC binders and it works pretty well. Thank you for your help.